# Android: Blinking fragment title

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

When I navigate to another fragment, its name is displayed like `fragment_card`, then it changes to my custom title. What can I do to apply my title immediately?

```
class CardFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentCardBinding>(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_card,
        container,
        false
    ).apply {

        updateTitle(title)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        // ...

    }.root
}
```

```
val Fragment.actionBar: ActionBar?
    get() = (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar

/**
 * Throws if action bar is not available
 */
var Fragment.title: String
    get() = requireNotNull(actionBar).title.toString()
    set(value) {
        requireNotNull(actionBar).title = value
    }

fun Fragment.updateTitle(title: String) {
    this.title = title
}
```

Comment: Entire code can be found [here](https://github.com/braille-systems/learn-braille/blob/master/android/app/src/main/java/com/github/braillesystems/learnbraille/ui/screens/practice/CardFragment.kt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem and just found the solution. The flickering title is the fragment label from navigation.xml (under the tag android:label). If you set it to its proper string value, there's even no need to update it in onCreate.

Comment: Great insight! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What about to updating it on "onAttach" or "onCreate" ?

Comment: Nothing changed. It looks like something changes the title before I set it. It could be `DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentCardBinding>`, so I changed to 
`updateTitle(title);  return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card, container, false)`
but the issue is still here.

Comment: I don’t think that the issue will be that line. onAttach or onCreate methods runs before onCreateView

Comment: Yes, but I should call `super.on...` in overriding methods anyway. And I cannot find information about the same issue from other people, so I'm trying to find unusual things in my code (and unable to find any :( )

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may find a temporary workaround here:
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4571#issuecomment-501110274

you may also like to see these resources:

http://www.datanotes.org/23-avoid-flickering-view-title-with-ionicframework-and-android
https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3864#issuecomment-417009798

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.